# Polygon to raster. How to keep same values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rasterization

I have a polygon with values 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27 an 30. These are the time it takes for the firetruck to reach certain destinations. Now i want to compare these to another raster that have time for helicopter to reach destinations.

The problem is that when i convert the polygon to raster it doesn't keep the old values, it instead makes new ones 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20.

Is there a way to keep old values so i can make a correct calculation between the two rasters?

[image: Pic]

Comment: Does anyone know how to answer this question in R or QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

when you convert a feature to raster, you need to select the field that contains the values to be transfered. Make sure that the field used is the one you need.